# How to overcome max upload size limit in Wordpress 3.1 running on Windows 2003 IIS6

Tags: file-upload, wordpress, iis-metabase, windows-2003-webserver

i am trying to increase the max upload size in wordpress 3.1 multisite-installation running on windows 2003 iis6, but all methods i try (from editing php.ini, putting it in wp-admin as well as in the root, editing the htaccess, editing the metabase.xml, restarting the server) give nothing, i still get the same error saying that the file exceeds the allowed 2MB....that's frustrating... any workaround and please, step by step...thanks!

i have my pretty urls thanks to isapi, but this - this frustrates me since i can't upload any audio mp3 file, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has these two settings that govern uploading files:

```
* upload_max_filesize
* post_max_size
```

Have you modified both of those? Additionally, IIS has an AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed metabase property that defaults to 2MB. You can modify it with the IIS manager application.

Comment: yes, i have modified them both, and i have modified too the metabase.xml incresing the size, nothig helped... thaks for your answer

Comment: sorry for typing errors... i did everything you have just suggested, and thanks again!

Comment: Have you restarted IIS after making those changes?

Comment: yes i ahve, that's why i am posting my question here... i did all the changes, then i re-started the server - nope, nothing, still getting the 2MB limit error

Comment: i have restarted iis, i have restarted the server, nothing happens, still getting the error

Comment: i would pay for this, do you know where i can found somebody quickly? i need this to be solved by tomorrow? thanks, thanks

Comment: or if you can help, i will pay, of course... first time here, maybe it is contra the rules of the house?

Comment: Can you post the error message you get when you try to upload the file?

Comment: 1-08 Enjoy The Silence.mp3” has failed to upload due to an error
This file exceeds the maximum upload size for this site. - that's it (??)

Comment: How big is the mp3? There is one other php setting that may be relevant: memory_limit. Try adding it to your php configuration and restart IIS. Make sure upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are big enough for your mp3 (20M should be enough) and make sure that memory_limit is higher than either of those (64M is good).

Comment: the file is about 5-6 MB, and yes, i have already set up my php.ini, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, and the memory_limit is set up to 64M ..........

Comment: really frustrating since i have tried all methods out there, can't figure out what am i doing wrong?? thank you for your assistance and effort

Comment: OK, so maybe the problem is that the php.ini values aren't being used. Can you create a new php file and put the following:

echo ini_get('memory_limit') . ' ' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . ' ' . ini_get('post_max_size');

Comment: 128M 2M 8M - this is what i got